# flex cannot open file in sh script

Tags: cygwin, flex-lexer

I use flex on cygwin package for Windows to build lexical analyzer. 
I created file test.lex with rules
When i use this commands in command line

```
flex -i test.lex
cc lex.yy.c -lfl
./a
```

It works fine. But when i tried to make sh file (compile_flex.sh) with this commands and run file

```
./compile_flex.sh
```

I received error

```
flex: can't open test.lex
```

I tried to put different paths to my file

```
~/test.lex
/home/user/test.lex
c:\\cygwin64\\home\\user\\test.lex
```

But it doesn't work! I always receive message that file not found. 
When I put command

```
vi test.lex
```

In my .sh file it works good and file is opened in vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out with my problem. I use windows editor (notepad++) for create .sh file. When I changed line separator from \n\r to \n in preferences, it was working fine